# how can I make the internal editor the default editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want the default edior to be the internal editor and not the system editor.

I have it configured in window->preferences->file associations to use default internal xml editor for *.xml yet eclipse always tries to open files with OS system editor. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564065/changing-default-xml-editor-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The editor type is mapped to file type; you can do this on a per-workspace (global) or per-project basis.

It should be pretty much as simple as this:

- http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftxprefs.html
- Go into "Help, Install Software, What is already installed?" and make sure you have "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" installed.  You you don't, then get it.
- Finally, create a *new*, "clean" project, add an XML file, and verify it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found this question but the answers didn't help me, so I continued searching and found the answer here http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml

Basically, in the Preferences, General > Editors > File Associations, then define your file types (if not already there), and select an editor.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click on File from Project,

Select Open with ....
Select your editor